# Definite Integral of $\int_{0}^{\pi /4}\tan x\cdotp \ln( 1+\sin 2x)\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How do I prove or disprove that:

$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\pi /4}\tan x\cdotp \ln( 1+\sin 2x) \ \mathrm dx=\frac{\pi ^{2}}{48}$?

I can't get around with this integral. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Anyway, one of the possible ways could be to expand the logarithm.

Comment: @MarianG. I have tried to do that. It gets complicated.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

The problem is not too hard using Feynman's trick
$$I(a)=\int\limits _{0}^{\frac\pi 4}\tan (x)\, \log( 1+a\sin (2x))\, dx$$
$$I'(a)=\int\limits _{0}^{\frac\pi 4}\frac{\sin (2 x) \tan (x)}{1+a \sin (2 x)}\, dx=2\int\limits _{0}^{1}\frac{ t^2}{\left(t^2+1\right) \left(t^2+2 a t+1\right)}\,dt$$

Use partial fraction decomposition to obtain the results. Then, Integrate $I'(a)$ from $0$ to $1$  knowing that $I(0)=0$

Comment: What did you substitute in place of t?

Comment: @Nothingspecial. This is the tangent half-angle substitution : $\tan(x)=t$